# When creating new view: "Base table or view not found" problem

Tags: views, database

When creating a new view and then trying to save it, I get this error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal.views_display' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO {views_display} (vid, id, display_title, display_plugin, position, display_options) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 11 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => default [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => Master [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => default [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => a:12:{s:5:"query";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:11:"views_query";s:7:"options";a:0:{}}s:6:"access";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:4:"perm";}s:5:"cache";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:4:"none";}s:12:"exposed_form";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:5:"basic";}s:5:"pager";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"full";s:7:"options";a:1:{s:14:"items_per_page";s:2:"10";}}s:12:"style_plugin";s:4:"list";s:10:"row_plugin";s:4:"node";s:6:"fields";a:1:{s:5:"title";a:8:{s:2:"id";s:5:"title";s:5:"table";s:4:"node";s:5:"field";s:5:"title";s:5:"label";s:0:"";s:5:"alter";a:8:{s:10:"alter_text";i:0;s:9:"make_link";i:0;s:8:"absolute";i:0;s:4:"trim";i:0;s:13:"word_boundary";i:0;s:8:"ellipsis";i:0;s:10:"strip_tags";i:0;s:4:"html";i:0;}s:10:"hide_empty";i:0;s:10:"empty_zero";i:0;s:12:"link_to_node";i:1;}}s:7:"filters";a:3:{s:6:"status";a:6:{s:5:"value";i:1;s:5:"table";s:4:"node";s:5:"field";s:6:"status";s:2:"id";s:6:"status";s:6:"expose";a:1:{s:8:"operator";b:0;}s:5:"group";i:1;}s:4:"type";a:4:{s:2:"id";s:4:"type";s:5:"table";s:4:"node";s:5:"field";s:4:"type";s:5:"value";a:1:{s:7:"teznews";s:7:"teznews";}}s:3:"tid";a:5:{s:2:"id";s:3:"tid";s:5:"table";s:14:"taxonomy_index";s:5:"field";s:3:"tid";s:5:"value";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:10:"vocabulary";s:4:"tags";}}s:5:"sorts";a:1:{s:7:"created";a:4:{s:2:"id";s:7:"created";s:5:"table";s:4:"node";s:5:"field";s:7:"created";s:5:"order";s:4:"DESC";}}s:5:"title";s:11:"Latest News";s:11:"row_options";a:3:{s:10:"build_mode";s:4:"full";s:5:"links";b:1;s:8:"comments";b:0;}} ) in views_db_object->save_row() (line 2224 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\includes\view.inc).

I have struggled with this for a while and have used SQL snippets to create tables which were previously 'missing'. I have also googled it extensively, without seeming to find an answer, and sure that someone will understand what the problem relates to immediately. This is the first time I have come up against it. This is a fresh install of drupal 7.22 and I have never experienced this problem previously whilst building drupal sites.

I have tried updating everything and wondered if there was some way to install a clean version of 'views' in core or if this related to another problem.

Any advice from a more skilled set of eyes would be invaluable.

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'drupal.views_display' doesn't exist.
```

That pretty much sums up the problem. The table wasn't created in the initial setup of views. Without knowing more I can't tell you exactly what's going on but a couple of things you could try is to run update.php and check for the issue in the [views queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/views?status=All&categories=bug). You may have a mysql issue as well that's not allowing the table to be created.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled drupal and did a new database and that fixed it. A shorter workaround as it happens.